# QWebEngineView createWindow

Tags: qt, qtwebengine

OK bending my brain trying to make sense of QWebEngine.

I understand the concept of implementing virtual functions but I'm unsure how to get the url that the user has clicked being a newTab/newWindow link that a page or view has requested.

```
QWebEngineView * WebEngineTabView::createWindow(QWebEnginePage::WebWindowType type)
{
// signal Main window for a new view( @URL )
emit requestNewTab(page()->requestedUrl());
}
```

This is for an educational GPL browser app
Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you saw how this done in the [demobrowser example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-browser-webview-cpp.html)?

```
QWebEnginePage *WebPage::createWindow(QWebEnginePage::WebWindowType type)
{
    if (type == QWebEnginePage::WebBrowserTab) {
        return mainWindow()->tabWidget()->newTab()->page();
    } else if (type == QWebEnginePage::WebBrowserWindow) {
        BrowserApplication::instance()->newMainWindow();
        BrowserMainWindow *mainWindow = BrowserApplication::instance()->mainWindow();
        return mainWindow->currentTab()->page();
    } else {
        PopupWindow *popup = new PopupWindow(profile());
        popup->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
        popup->show();
        return popup->page();
    }
}
```

If you still want to delegate this work, notifying the mainwindow/app/whatever, you probably can intercept clicks and store links, but I'm not sure about calls order, plus you have to pay attention for cases when requested window is just a "new tab" (an empty tab without url):

```
bool WebPage::acceptNavigationRequest(const QUrl & url, NavigationType type, bool isMainFrame)
{
    switch( type )
    {
        case QWebEnginePage::NavigationTypeLinkClicked:
        {
            mLastClickedLink = url; //-- clear it in WebPage::createWindow
            return true;
        }
        default:
            return QWebEnginePage::acceptNavigationRequest( url, type, isMainFrame );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you check the Qt source code, you will see that after the function QWebEnginePage::createWindow is called to create the QWebEnginePage pointer, this pointer will have some data written into it. See https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtwebengine.git/tree/src/webenginewidgets/api/qwebenginepage.cpp?h=5.9#n404

For me the following example works:

```
class MyWebEnginePage : public QWebEnginePage
{
    ...
    QWebEnginePage *createWindow(WebWindowType type) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
    {
        QWebEnginePage *page = new QWebEnginePage();
        connect(page, &QWebEnginePage::urlChanged, this, [this] (const QUrl &url) {
            emit newPageUrlChanged(url);
        }

        return page;
    }

signals:
    void newPageUrlChanged(const QUrl &url);
};

class MyClass : public QObject
{
    ...
    MyClass()
    {
        connect(m_pPage, &MyWebEnginePage::newPageUrlChanged, this, &MyClass::onNewPageUrlChanged);
    }
private slots:
    void onNewPageUrlChanged(const QUrl &url)
    {
        qDebug() << url; // new url will be printed here
    }
private:
    MyWebEnginePage *m_pPage;
}
```

Hope this helps